# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserName', table 'ini3_py_account.dbo.Ini3_UserLogin'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: sql-server

I try to make a registration form but it doesn't let me. It says this:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserName', table 'ini3_py_account.dbo.Ini3_UserLogin'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

```
conn.execute("insert into Ini3_UserLogin (UserID,Password,IsDelete,Birthday,Sex) values ('"&UserName&"','"& oldpass &"','N','19881111','0') ")
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, what about it do you not understand? You are trying to insert the username into the `UserID` column, is that your problem?

Comment: Also, please go and read up on SQL injection, building SQL strings like this can be very dangerous.

Comment: I hope you're not storing passwords as plain text as well. Ideally they should be hashed and salted.

Answer (score 1):

in place of userid write username

```
conn.execute("insert into Ini3_UserLogin 
             (UserName,Password,IsDelete,Birthday,Sex) 
             values 
             ('"&UserName&"','"& oldpass &"','N','19881111','0') ")
```

edit

After @Larnu suggestion I m convinced that giving ans is not solution it should be appropriate

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = "Connection String";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Ini3_UserLogin 
(UserName,Password,IsDelete,Birthday,Sex) 
values 
(@UserName,@oldpass,@IsDelete,@BirthDay,@Sex)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpass",oldpass);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDelete",'N');
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday",'19881111');
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex",rdbMale.Checked?0:1);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```